# If picturebox.image == Properties.Resources.ImageA

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Im making few buttons(picturebox) that then you click them they change image.

I tryed this code but it always skips to else.

Images are loaded from resources.

```
private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (pictureBox7.Image == KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalA)
       {
           pictureBox7.Image = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalB;
       }
       else
       {
            pictureBox7.Image = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalA;
       }
    }
```

Figured that out.

Insted comparing picturebox.image I set picturebox.tag and compare.

```
pictureBox7.Tag = "B";
if (pictureBox7.Tag.ToString() == "A")
   {
        pictureBox7.Image = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalB;
        pictureBox7.Tag = "B";
   }
   else
   {
        pictureBox7.Image = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalA;
        pictureBox7.Tag = "A";
   }
```

Comment: You always get a *new* instance of the image object when you use Properties.Resources.Mumble.  It will never match the instance you got before.  Use a variable to avoid creating copies.

Comment: If you solve your own problem, post an answer and, after a day or so, mark it accepted. That way your question will be marked as answered in the UI, and you'll even get a participation badge. Changing your title does not mark your question as answered in the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep local reference to your resources, because when you invoke `KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources...` you will always get new instance of object:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Bitmap _icopalABitmap = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalA;
    Bitmap _icopalBBitmap = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalB;

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (pictureBox7.Image == _icopalABitmap)
        {
            pictureBox7.Image = _icopalBBitmap;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox7.Image = _icopalABitmap;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox7.Image = _icopalABitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

please attention this code:

```
Bitmap _icopalABitmap = KaminuSkaiciuokle.Properties.Resources.IcopalA;
```

_icopalABitmap:it is name you ideal that.
KaminuSkaiciuokle: it aqual your project name.
IcopalA: is your picture name